# Регулярное выражение тел номеров Белоруссия +375;80 (мобильные операторы)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Могли бы подсказать универсальное регулярное выражение, которое бы забирало номер телефона в независимости от его формата, т.е., например, встречаются номера (мобильные операторы Белоруссии)

```
+375(хх)ххххххх 
+375ххххххххх 
:av:(12 цифр) 
80(хх)хххххххи 
80 хх хх хх ххх 
80 хх хх-хх-ххх 
80ххххххххх 
:av:(11 цифр) 
и т.д.
```

Comment: Что такое `:av:`? А удалить из строки не-цифры, по-моему, задача тривиальная...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/(?:\+375|80)\s?\(?\d\d\)?\s?\d\d(?:\d[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d|[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d\d|\d{5})/
```

- `\+375|80` - тут все понятно
- `\s?\(?\d\d\)?\s?` - код оператора (или чего там), в опциональном окружении скобок и/или пробелов
- `\d\d` - первые две цифры номера

  Далее три альтернативы остатка номера:
- `\d[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d` - формат `x-xx-xx`/`x xx xx`
- `[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d\d` - формат `-xx-xxx`/ `xx xxx`
- `\d{5}` - формат `xxxxx`

---

```js
const data = [
  '+375(12)2345678', 
  '+375 (12) 2345678', 
  '+375123456789', 
  '80(12)2345678', 
  '80 12 34 56 789', 
  '80 12 34-56-789', 
  '80 12 345 67 89', 
  '80 12 345-67-89', 
  '80123456789'
]; 

const regx = /^(?:\+375|80)\s?\(?\d\d\)?\s?\d\d(?:\d[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d|[\-\s]\d\d[\-\s]\d\d\d|\d{5})$/; 
const results = data.map(
  v => [v.padEnd(19, ' '), regx.test(v)].join('➝  ')
); 
document.body.textContent = results.join('\n');
```

```css
body { font: 14px monospace; white-space: pre; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так, идея вроде должна быть понятна:

```
^\s*((+[-()\s]*3[-()\s]*7[-()\s]*5|[-()\s]*8[-()\s]*0)([-()\s]*\d){9}|:av:([-()\s]*\d){11,12})\s*$
```